# Pull all triggers in various sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull triggers that have been set in multiple sheets and populate certain details into a google spreadsheet. I am however having an issue pulling triggers from different sheets.

```
function getAllTriggers() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  var idsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetIDs');

  var triggersSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Triggers');


  var data = idsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var spreadsheetId = data[i][0];  

    // Open the spreadsheet
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);


    var spreadsheetName = spreadsheet.getName();

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()

    // Iterate over each trigger
    for (var j = 0; j < triggers.length; j++) {
      var trigger = triggers[j];

      var triggerId = trigger.getUniqueId();
      var handlerFunction = trigger.getHandlerFunction();


      var event = trigger.getEventType().toString();


      triggersSheet.appendRow([spreadsheetId, spreadsheetName, event, "", handlerFunction, triggerId]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please describe the issue you are having in greater detail?

Comment: I believe ScriptApp can only display triggers for the current project.  So it would only see triggers for the active spreadsheet.  Opening another spreadsheet does not expose it triggers to ScriptApp.

Comment: Is there any way to get the data. I am attempting to build a master sheet where i can manage all my triggers.